# Re-starting an inactive media session called onDestroy immediately

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediasession

I've followed the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons#restarting-inactive-mediasessions) on restarting an inactive media session and, for some reason, `onDestroy` is being called immediately. It works when if I play some audio, then run the app again through Android Studio. When I try to restart playback `onMediaButtonEvent` is called and playback resumes as expected.

However if I let the device idle and `onDestroy` is called, if I then try to restart playback, `onMediaButtonEvent` is called (as expected) but then `onDestroy` is immediately called after that. There's no delay or anything, it just hits `onDestroy` immediately.

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {
    private ExoPlayer mPlayer;
    private MediaSessionCompat mMediaSessionCompat;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mMediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(this, MediaPlayerService.class.getSimpleName());
        mMediaSessionCompat.setCallback(mMediaSessionCallback);
        mMediaSessionCompat.setActive(true);

        mPlaybackBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder();
        mPlaybackBuilder.setActions(
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS |
                                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT);
                                
        setSessionToken(mMediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken());

        mPlaybackAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                .build();

        mPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(mContext).build();
        mPlayer.addListener(new PlayerEventListener());
    }
    
    private final MediaSessionCompat.Callback mMediaSessionCallback = new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
    
        @Override
        public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
        
            KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) mediaButtonEvent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);

            if (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY && keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyEvent.getRepeatCount() == 0)
            {
                PlayAudio();
                //onDestroy is called immediately
            }

            return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);
        }


        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();

            StopAudio();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            super.onPlay();

            PlayAudio();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

            PauseAudio();
        }
    };

    
     private class PlayerEventListener implements Player.Listener {

        @Override
        public void onPlaybackStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == Player.STATE_BUFFERING) {
  
            } else if (state == Player.STATE_READY) {


            } else if (state == Player.STATE_ENDED)
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE);

        mMediaSessionCompat.setMetadata(null);
        mMediaSessionCompat.setActive(false);
        mMediaSessionCompat.release();
        
        mPlayer.release();
    }
        
}
```

UPDATE:

I have narrowed it down to releasing the media session: `mMediaSessionCompat.release()`. If I remove that line, then `onDestroy` is not called immediately.

Comment: Did you [read the documentation about the lifecycle of your service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice#service-lifecycle)? You don't seem to be doing [any of the things you are supposed to be doing when `onPlay` is called](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/mediasession-callbacks), including calling `startService`. Is there some code missing?

Comment: I am calling `startService` in onPlay. The actual media service runs fine, it's just restarting an inactive service that I'm having an issue with. I didn't want to put the entire media service code in.